# definir variavel de ambiente no application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, propriedade

Tenho um projecto em Spring boot onde no application.properties queria definir a localização de ficheiros que vou processar. Não sei a melhor forma de o fazer. Queria ter o directório parametrizável numa variável de ambiente no sistema. Só que não consigo por a funcionar.

Exemplo

```
filesdir = ${BASEDIRFiles}
```

Neste momento tenho

```
filesdir = /home/teste/
```

E no sistema tinha uma variável de ambiente com o nome BASEDIRFiles com um directório onde estão os ficheiros.
Não queria definir de forma clara o directório no application.properties. Alguma ideia de como o fazer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A documentação oficial sobre [externalização de configuração](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) do Spring Boot tem todos os detalhes sobre isto.

Antes de mais nada, parametrizar tudo o que se refere a acesso externo ao seu programa é boa prática em geral, facilitando testes e portabilidade para novos ambientes.

No caso do framework, basta você definir uma entrada no arquivo `application.properties` (ou `application.yaml`, que acredito ser mais legível e tem sido recomendado recentemente), da seguinte forma:

```
app.filesdir=/home/test
```

Coloquei o prefixo `app` porque é uma boa prática segregar o que é específico do seu aplicativo de outras configurações. Se você olhar as demais configurações padrão do Spring Boot, vai ver que todas elas seguem uma espécie de hierarquia usando prefixos.

Para usar o valor de `app.filesdir` em seu programa, você pode injetar o valor em algum Spring Bean qualquer assim:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {

    @Value("${app.filesdir}")
    private String name;

    // ...

}
```

Ok, até aqui vimos como usar a variável com seu valor padrão estaticamente definido.

Entretanto, você pode sobrescrever a variável usando, por exemplo, um parâmetro no comando que inicia o Spring Boot Application:

```
java -jar myapp.jar --app.filesdir=/home/teste
```

Por outro lado, se você quiser definir o valor numa variável de ambiente, pode fazer isto também e, segundo a ordem especificada na documentação, ela vai sobrescrever o valor definido no `application.properties`.

Apenas tome cuidado aqui porque se você alterar uma variável de ambiente em outro terminal ou numa interface do seu Sistema Operacional, ela não vai refletir imediatamente no seu terminal ou IDE que já está aberto, teria que fechar e abrir novamente para ter o novo valor da variável.

Finalmente, o Spring Boot permite que você faça referência a variáveis de ambiente no seu arquivo de configuração. Exemplo:

```
app.filesdir=${APP_FILES_DIR}
```

No entanto isto é útil apenas quando você quer usar um nome de variável diferente internamente no aplicativo em relação ao nome da variável definido no ambiente.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação! Percebi a ideia.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a seguinte sintaxe:

```
spring.datasource.username = ${MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password = ${MYSQL_DB_PORT}
```